# Merge values in a column (B) based on common values in column (A) in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

**Question**: Using SQL, how would you Merge values in a column (B) based on common values in column (A)?

**Table Structure**: I have a SQL table (shown below), where *Column A* has ID's and *Column B* contains Text related to ID's and *Column C* contains Rank Order (*the order in which text should be should be sorted*).

| ID | TEXT | RANK_ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC001 | ID: ABC001 - NEAREST LANDMARK - SHOPPING CENTRE | -999 |
| ABC001 | TRAVEL 80 M NORTH FROM SC | -900 |
| ABC001 | THROUGH PEDESTRIAN CROSSING | 10.1 |
| ABC002 | ID: ABC002 - NEAREST LANDMARK - PUBLIC TOILET | -999 |
| ABC002 | TRAVEL 150 M NORTH FROM SC | -900 |
| ABC002 | THROUGH PARK ACCESS RD | 10.1 |
| ABC003 | ID: ABC003 - NEAREST LANDMARK - REHABILITATION CENTRE | -999 |
| ABC003 | TRAVEL 1300M WEST FROM RC | -900 |
| ABC003 | THROUGH UNMADE RD | 10.1 |
| ABC003 | LOCKED GATES | 10.5 |
| ABC003 | CALL RC FOR ACCESS | 20.1 |

**Expected End Result**: The resultant table should look like the table shown below:

| ID | TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| ABC001 | ID: ABC001 - NEAREST LANDMARK - SHOPPING CENTRE TRAVEL 80 M NORTH FROM SC THROUGH PEDESTRIAN CROSSING |
| ABC002 | ID: ABC002 - NEAREST LANDMARK - PUBLIC TOILET TRAVEL 150 M NORTH FROM SC THROUGH PARK ACCESS RD |
| ABC003 | ID: ABC003 - NEAREST LANDMARK - REHABILITATION CENTRE TRAVEL 1300M WEST FROM RC THROUGH UNMADE RD LOCKED GATES CALL RC FOR ACCESS |

Comment: Seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Comment: Please tag the DBMS that you are using along with the version. E.g., `Oracle 11g`, `MSSQL 2012` etc.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gordon, LISTAGG Works on SQLServer 2016 onwards, where I am on SQLServer 2012.
But I found **STRING_AGG** works well. The following query is the solution.

```
    select ID, STRING_AGG(TEXT, CHAR(13)) within group (Order by RANK_ORDER) as TEXT
    from t
    GROUP BY ID
```

I am unable to get Carriage Return in results, it looks like SSMS issue.

Cheers,
Ankit

Comment: Are you sure that you are on `SQL server 2012`? Because STRING_AGG was introduced in `SQL Server 2017`

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you can represent this as:

```
select id,
       listagg(text, '; ') within group (order by rank_order) as text
from t
group by id;
```

Although most databases support this functionality, the exact syntax depends on the database -- as does inserting a newline character (which might also depend on the operating system).